# EventHandler<T> argument contravariance in .NET 4.0. Does it match its defining type?

Tags: c#, events, .net-4.0, delegates, contravariance

According to [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173174.aspx) delegates in event handlers support *contravariance*, for example you can use one event handler with `EventArgs` as its generic parameter of `EventHandler<T>` for different event that has other parameter:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
       var a = new A();
        a.event1 += a_event1;
        a.event2 += a_event1;
    }

    static void a_event1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {}
}

public class A
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs>        event1;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgsDerived> event2;
}

public class EventArgsDerived : EventArgs
{}
```

I noticed that `EventHandler` definition is :

```
public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs e);
```

and generic `TEventArgs` parameter is defined without using an **in** Keyword.

So how contravariance is supported and how compiler accepts base class parameter of type `EventArgs` for event handler?

Comment: How do you say it supports contravariance? Example please?

Comment: The MSDN documentation says that DELEGATES support variance; it doesn't talk about Event Handlers in particular.

Comment: `KeyDown` and `MouseClick` isn't using `EventHandler<T>`. They declare separate handlers themselves. Refer this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2835078/2530848)

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel : That's right. I modified the example.

Comment: @Dennis_E : yes, but Event Handlers in events are delegates that support contravariance. I looked for definition and I expected **in** keyword.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54907236/why-wasnt-teventargs-made-contravariant-in-the-standard-event-pattern-in-the-n

Answer (score 1):

Contravariance is implicit through the use of `EventArgs` base class in standard event handling pattern and `TEventArgs` is only used as an **input** parameter.

The variance that you mean (using `in` and `out`) is for type conversion, for exapmle:

```
var a = new EventHandler<EventArgs>((o, e) => { return; });
var b = new EventHandler<ErrorEventArgs>((o, e) => { return; });
b = a;
```

Gives you a compile error because `TEventArgs` is not specified as `in`. But the following is legal:

```
var x = new Action<EventArgs>((e) => { return; });
var y = new Action<ErrorEventArgs>((e) => { return; });
y = x;
```

Comment: It gives compile error because it violates constructor argument. If you use method name in assignment as in my example it will compile.

Comment: Then why doesn't it generate an error on second case ? Look at it this way, in your case event1 expects an object as it's first argument and an EventArgs as it's second, so it doesn't care if you pass it an ErrorEventArgs or anything else that derives from EventArgs. All it needs is EventArgs functionality.

Comment: It's exactly contravariance issue in delegates and needs **in** keyword. In your case `Action<T>` is defined as `public delegate void Action<in T>(T obj);` and has the keyword.

Comment: Yes, and that's why I can't cast an EventHandler<EventArgs> to EventHandler<ErrorEventArgs> BUT I can use an EventHander<EventArgs> delegate INSTEAD OF EventHandler<ErrorEventArgs> delegate.

Comment: This is allowed if generic parameter is used with **in** keyword like 'Action <in T>'. This keyword is not present in 'EventHandler<T>' which is my question.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing *generic covariance/contravariance* with *method group conversion variance*.

As you observe, EventHandler<TEventArgs> does **not** support generic contravariance in its type argument due to the lack of the **in** keyword. This type of variance was added in C# 4.0.

But you can still assign handlers that take less derived types in their argument list thanks to method group conversion variance. This is an older type of variance support, that was added in C# 2.0. You can read more about it in Eric Lipperts [blog post on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/19/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-three-member-group-conversion-variance.aspx).